# Babel async/await only returning the promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-6, babeljs

My issue is that the following code example will only return the Promise object and async/await doesn't work at all.

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

function doAsync() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve('result')
        }, 2000)
    })
}

async function doStuff() {
    try {
        return await doAsync()
    } catch (err) {
        console.err(err);
    }
};

doStuff() // Returns the promise object
console.log('log') // Runs before timeout
```

Babel config

```
{
    presets: ["es2015"],
    plugins: [
      "transform-class-properties",
      "syntax-decorators",
      "transform-decorators-legacy",
      "syntax-async-functions",
      "transform-regenerator"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work at all"? I may be wrong, but AFAIK async functions return promises.

Comment: It means that Babel should transform the code with regenerator, to wait for the promise to get resolved. The last console.log() should only run after the promise is resolved (after setTimeout)

Comment: @wintercounter: You don't `await` the `doStuff()`. Or put your logging statement inside that function after the `await` (remove the `return`) and the timeout *will* be awaited.

Comment: @wintercounter: Only `async function`s will get transformed with regenerator. Calls to those functions are not implicitly awaited; why would they be?

Comment: @Bergi maybe little off-topic, but does it mean that `await doStuff()` is an syntax error?

Comment: @bgoscinski Not unless it is inside another `async` function :D

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doStuff` is an *asynchronous* function, which returns a promise. You're not waiting for the promise to be fulfilled or rejected, but instead, you're logging to the console right away. The behavior you're observing is correct. If you want to log to the console only when the promise is fulfilled, chain a `then` call to the promise returned from `doStuff`.

Comment: Understood, i have to write my code inside the try statement after the await.